# Draw ontop of a graphic inserted using label(graphic(…), …)

Tags: asymptote

I'd like to use Asymptote to compose an existing EPS file and draw some stuff onto it. I'm doing this using the [suggested method](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/label.html#index-graphic) of using `label()` and `graphic()` to place the EPS file on the canvas. The problem is that the imported graphics, being treated as a label, stay on top of all drawing that is done afterwards.

Let's say I have an EPS file generated using the following Asymptote file `foo.asy` (in my case the EPS actually contains a raster image, so I can't just include the commands to create the EPS in my final Asymptote file):

```
fill(circle((0, 0), 10), blue + white);
```

And now I include the EPS file from the following Asymptote file `bar.asy`:

```
label(graphic("foo.eps"), (0, 0));
draw((-10, -10) -- (10, 10), black + 2);
```

This results in the blue circle being drawn on top of the black line.

Is there either a way to somehow draw ontop of a label or is there another way to include an EPS file without using `label()`?

Comment: Have you tried using the `layer()` command?

Comment: @CharlesStaats No. It seems I didn't thoroughly read the documentation I linked to. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of using Asymptote to draw on top of an image from a file may be found here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129801/484

The key step you are missing is to include the line

```
layer();
```

after you include the image, but before you draw anything that should go on top of it.

**Explanation** (for general readers—the OP seems to understand this): In Asymptote (excluding 3d stuff), by default, labels are always on top of "drawing" elements so that the labels won't be hidden. Since images are imported as a kind of label, only other labels will go on top of it; drawing elements will go beneath it, and themselves will be hidden.

However, the `layer()` command changes the default: anything after a `layer()` command goes on top of everything before it, allowing drawn elements to go on top of labels.